# Aggregation Accumulate Inner Objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new with mongo aggregations, and I need a help with creating one,

I have a collection of the following document as an example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afc2f06e1da131c9802071e"),
    "_class" : "Traveler",
    "name" : "John Due",
    "startTimestamp" : 1526476550933,
    "endTimestamp" : 1526476554823,
    "source" : "istanbul",
    "cities" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "ef8f6b26328f-0663202f94faeaeb-3981",
            "name" : "Moscow",
            "timestamp" : 1526476550940,
            "timeSpent" : 3180
        },

        {
            "_id" : "ef8f6b26328f-0663202f94faeaeb-1122",
            "name" : "Cairo",
            "timestamp" : 1625476550940,
            "timeSpent" : 318000,
        },
         {
            "_id" : "ef8f6b26328f-0663202f94faeaeb-3981",
            "name" : "Moscow",
            "timestamp" : 15211276550940,
            "timeSpent" : 318011
        }


    ],
    "variables" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "cd4318a83c9b-a8478d76bfd3e4b6-5967",
            "name" : "Customer Profile",
            "lastValue" : "",
            "values" : [],
            "additionalData" : {}
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "366cb8c07996-c62c37a87a86d526-d3e7",
            "name" : "Target Telephony Queue",
            "lastValue" : "",
            "values" : [],
            "additionalData" : {}
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "4ed84742da33-d70ba8a809b712f3-bdf4",
            "name" : "IMEI",
            "lastValue" : "",
            "values" : [],
            "additionalData" : {}
        }, 

        {
            "_id" : "c8103687c1c8-97d749e349d785c8-9154",
            "name" : "Budget",
            "defaultValue" : "",
            "lastValue" : "",
            "values" : [ 
                {
                    "value" : "3000",
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1526476550940),
                    "element" : "c8103687c1c8-97d749e349d785c8-9154"
                }
            ],
            "additionalData" : {}
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to have a resulting document showing the how many times each city have been visited by each traveler in the collection, and the average budget (budget is an element in the variables array

so the resulting document will be similar to:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5afc2f06e1da131c9802071e"),
     "_class" : "Traveler",
     "name" : "John Due",
     "startTimestamp" : 1526476550933,
     "endTimestamp" : 1526476554823,
     "source" : "istanbul",
    "cities" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "ef8f6b26328f-0663202f94faeaeb-3981",
            "name" : "Moscow",
            "visited":2
        },
        {
            "_id" : "ef8f6b26328f-0663202f94faeaeb-1122",
            "name" : "Cairo",
            "visited":1
        }
    ],
    "variables" : [ 
        {
                "_id" : "c8103687c1c8-97d749e349d785c8-9154",
                "name" : "Budget",
                "defaultValue" : "",
                "lastValue" : "",
                "values" : [ 
                    {
                        "value" : "3000",
                    }
                ],
            }
    ],
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick note, you need to change your `"value"` field inside the `"values"` to be numeric, since it's presently a string. But on to the answer:

If you have access to [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) from MongoDB 3.4, then you can actually do something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "cities": {
       "$reduce": {
         "input": "$cities",
         "initialValue": [],
         "in": {
           "$cond": {
             "if": { "$ne": [{ "$indexOfArray": ["$$value._id", "$$this._id"] }, -1] },
             "then": {
               "$concatArrays": [
                 { "$filter": {
                   "input": "$$value",
                   "as": "v",
                   "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this._id", "$$v._id" ] }
                 }},
                 [{
                   "_id": "$$this._id",
                   "name": "$$this.name",
                   "visited": {
                     "$add": [
                       { "$arrayElemAt": [
                         "$$value.visited",
                         { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$value._id", "$$this._id" ] }
                       ]},
                       1
                     ]
                   }
                 }]
               ]
             },
             "else": {
               "$concatArrays": [
                 "$$value",
                 [{
                   "_id": "$$this._id",
                   "name": "$$this.name",
                   "visited": 1
                 }]
               ]
             }
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "variables": {
       "$map": {
         "input": {
           "$filter": {
             "input": "$variables",
             "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.name", "Budget"] } 
           }
         },
         "in": {
           "_id": "$$this._id",
           "name": "$$this.name",
           "defaultValue": "$$this.defaultValue",
           "lastValue": "$$this.lastValue",
           "value": { "$avg": "$$this.values.value" }
         }
       }
     }
  }}
])
```

If you have MongoDB 3.6, you can clean that up a bit with [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "cities": {
       "$reduce": {
         "input": "$cities",
         "initialValue": [],
         "in": {
           "$cond": {
             "if": { "$ne": [{ "$indexOfArray": ["$$value._id", "$$this._id"] }, -1] },
             "then": {
               "$concatArrays": [
                 { "$filter": {
                   "input": "$$value",
                   "as": "v",
                   "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this._id", "$$v._id" ] }
                 }},
                 [{
                   "_id": "$$this._id",
                   "name": "$$this.name",
                   "visited": {
                     "$add": [
                       { "$arrayElemAt": [
                         "$$value.visited",
                         { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$value._id", "$$this._id" ] }
                       ]},
                       1
                     ]
                   }
                 }]
               ]
             },
             "else": {
               "$concatArrays": [
                 "$$value",
                 [{
                   "_id": "$$this._id",
                   "name": "$$this.name",
                   "visited": 1
                 }]
               ]
             }
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "variables": {
       "$map": {
         "input": {
           "$filter": {
             "input": "$variables",
             "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.name", "Budget"] } 
           }
         },
         "in": {
           "$mergeObjects": [
             "$$this",
             { "values": { "$avg": "$$this.values.value" } }
           ]
         }
       }
     }
  }}
])
```

But it's more or less the same thing except we keep the `additionalData`

Going back a little before that, then you can always [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `"cities"` to accumulate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$cities" },
  { "$group": {
     "_id": { 
       "_id": "$_id",
       "cities": {
         "_id": "$cities._id",
         "name": "$cities.name"
       }
     },
     "_class": { "$first": "$class" },
     "name": { "$first": "$name" },
     "startTimestamp": { "$first": "$startTimestamp" },
     "endTimestamp" : { "$first": "$endTimestamp" },
     "source" : { "$first": "$source" },
     "variables": { "$first": "$variables" },
     "visited": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
     "_id": "$_id._id",
     "_class": { "$first": "$class" },
     "name": { "$first": "$name" },
     "startTimestamp": { "$first": "$startTimestamp" },
     "endTimestamp" : { "$first": "$endTimestamp" },
     "source" : { "$first": "$source" },
     "cities": {
       "$push": {
         "_id": "$_id.cities._id",
         "name": "$_id.cities.name",
         "visited": "$visited"
       }
     },
     "variables": { "$first": "$variables" },
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
     "variables": {
       "$map": {
         "input": {
           "$filter": {
             "input": "$variables",
             "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.name", "Budget"] } 
           }
         },
         "in": {
           "_id": "$$this._id",
           "name": "$$this.name",
           "defaultValue": "$$this.defaultValue",
           "lastValue": "$$this.lastValue",
           "value": { "$avg": "$$this.values.value" }
         }
       }
     }
  }}
])
```

All return (almost) the same thing:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5afc2f06e1da131c9802071e"),
        "_class" : "Traveler",
        "name" : "John Due",
        "startTimestamp" : 1526476550933,
        "endTimestamp" : 1526476554823,
        "source" : "istanbul",
        "cities" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "ef8f6b26328f-0663202f94faeaeb-1122",
                        "name" : "Cairo",
                        "visited" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "ef8f6b26328f-0663202f94faeaeb-3981",
                        "name" : "Moscow",
                        "visited" : 2
                }
        ],
        "variables" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "c8103687c1c8-97d749e349d785c8-9154",
                        "name" : "Budget",
                        "defaultValue" : "",
                        "lastValue" : "",
                        "value" : 3000
                }
        ]
}
```

The first two forms are of course the most optimal thing to do since they are simply working "within" the same document at all times.

Operators like [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) allow "accumulation" expressions on arrays, so we can use it here to keep a "reduced" array which we test for the unique `"_id"` value using [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) in order to see if the there already is an accumulated item that matches. A result of `-1` means it's not there.

In order construct a "reduced array" we take the `"initialValue"` of `[]` as an empty array and then add to it via [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/). All of that process is decided via the "ternary" [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator which considers the `"if"` condition and `"then"` either "joins" the output of the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) on the current `$$value` to exclude the current index `_id` entry, with of course another "array" representing the singular object.

For that "object" we again use the [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) to actually get the matched index since we know that the item "is there", and use that to extract the current `"visited"` value from that entry via [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) to it in order to increment.

In the `"else"` case we simply add an "array" as an "object" which just has a default `"visited"` value of `1`. Using both those cases effectively accumulates unique values within the array to output.

In the latter version, we just [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array and use successive [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages in order to first "count" on the unique inner entries, and then "re-construct the array" into the similar form.

Using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) looks far more simple, but since what it actually does is take a copy of the document for every array entry, then this actually adds considerable overhead to processing. In modern versions there are generally array operators which mean you don't need to use this unless your intention is to "accumulate across documents". So if you actually need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on a value of a key from "inside" an array, then that is where you actually do need to use it.

As for the `"variables"` then we can simply use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) again here to get the matching `"Budget"` entry. We do this as the input to the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator which allows "re-shaping" of the array content. We mainly want that so you can take the content of the `"values"` ( once you make it all numeric ) and use the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) operator, which is supplied that "field path notation" form directly to the array values because it can in fact return a result from such an input.

That generally makes the tour of pretty much ALL of the main "array operators" for the aggregation pipeline ( excluding the "set" operators ) all within a single pipeline stage.

Also don't ever forget that you just about always want to [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with regular [Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-selectors) as the "very first stage" of any aggregation pipeline in order to just select the documents you need. Ideally using an index.

---

#### Alternates

Alternates are working through the documents in client code. It generally would not be recommended since all methods above show they actually "reduce" the content as returned from the server, as is generally the point of "server aggregations".

It "may" be possible due to the "document based" nature that larger result sets may take considerably more time using `$unwind` and client processing could be an option, but I would consider it far more likely

Below is a listing that demonstrates applying a transform to the cursor stream as results are returned doing the same thing. There are three demonstrated versions of the transform, showing "exactly" the same logic as above, a implementation with `lodash` methods for accumulation, and a "natural" accumulation on the `Map` implementation:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const { chain } = require('lodash');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

const transform = ({ cities, variables, ...d }) => ({
  ...d,
  cities: cities.reduce((o,{ _id, name }) =>
    (o.map(i => i._id).indexOf(_id) != -1)
      ? [
          ...o.filter(i => i._id != _id),
          { _id, name, visited: o.find(e => e._id === _id).visited + 1 }
        ]
      : [ ...o, { _id, name, visited: 1 } ]
  , []).sort((a,b) => b.visited - a.visited),
  variables: variables.filter(v => v.name === "Budget")
    .map(({ values, additionalData, ...v }) => ({
      ...v,
      values: (values != undefined)
        ? values.reduce((o,e) => o + e.value, 0) / values.length
        : 0
    }))
});

const alternate = ({ cities, variables, ...d }) => ({
  ...d,
  cities: chain(cities)
    .groupBy("_id")
    .toPairs()
    .map(([k,v]) =>
      ({
        ...v.reduce((o,{ _id, name }) => ({ ...o, _id, name }),{}),
        visited: v.length
      })
    )
    .sort((a,b) => b.visited - a.visited)
    .value(),
  variables: variables.filter(v => v.name === "Budget")
    .map(({ values, additionalData, ...v }) => ({
      ...v,
      values: (values != undefined)
        ? values.reduce((o,e) => o + e.value, 0) / values.length
        : 0
    }))

});

const natural = ({ cities, variables, ...d }) => ({
  ...d,
  cities: [
    ...cities
      .reduce((o,{ _id, name }) => o.set(_id,
        [ ...(o.has(_id) ? o.get(_id) : []), { _id, name } ]), new Map())
      .entries()
  ]
  .map(([k,v]) =>
    ({
      ...v.reduce((o,{ _id, name }) => ({ ...o, _id, name }),{}),
      visited: v.length
    })
  )
  .sort((a,b) => b.visited - a.visited),
  variables: variables.filter(v => v.name === "Budget")
    .map(({ values, additionalData, ...v }) => ({
      ...v,
      values: (values != undefined)
        ? values.reduce((o,e) => o + e.value, 0) / values.length
        : 0
    }))

});

(async function() {

  try {

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, opts);

    let db = client.db('test');
    let coll = db.collection('junk');

    let cursor = coll.find().map(natural);

    while (await cursor.hasNext()) {
      let doc = await cursor.next();
      log(doc);
    }

    client.close();

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer,
I see this solution is good with mongo 3.6 and higher, the problem that i'm using mongo 3.2.
anyway, I tried to accomplish the mission using group and unwind stages, this solved my problem but i'm not sure about best practice!

Comment: @MarwanJaber The top solution actually only requires 3.4, which is really the version "most" people should be running. There is a solution that works with 3.2 listed in the answer. "Best practice" is what you can do with the supported features you have. I think that even the "unwinding" approach is still better than returning the data to the client for reduction, and it would be ruled right out if you were actually accumulating beyond "within the document". Added some code to show you anyway